# Inefficient NIntegrate and Which

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, conditional

In version 10 a simple numerical integraton of piecewise function is highly inefficient:

```
f[x_] := Which[-1 <= x <= 0, x, 0 <= x, x^2, True, 0]
ϕ[x_] := NIntegrate[f[t], {t, -1, x}]
```

[image: in the version 10]

whereas in the version 5 it was much faster:

[image]

How can I speed up the plotting (what options in `Plot` or in `NIntegrate`)?

@Micheal E2

partially you were right - there is difference in a  number of points, however not so large like the diference in timing

[image] 
[image]

The Plot command was used to see difference in timing, however, 
for the same number of points older version is still better:

[image]
[image]

Comment: How many points are plotted in each version?

Answer (score 8):

`NIntegrate[f[t], {t, -1, x}]` integrates the same thing over and over again, when a point is needed by `Plot`.

Integrate what you need one time only:

```
f[x_] = Which[-1 <= x <= 0, x, 0 <= x, x^2, True, 0];
ϕ[x_] = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][g][t] == f[t], g[-1] == 0},
g, {t, -1.5, 1}][[1, 1, 2]][x];
Plot[ϕ[x], {x, -1.5, 1}]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was just  interested in the NIntegrate efficiency, maybe, I did not say it clearly.

Answer (score 6):

I agree `NDSolve` is the way to go, but I think I know why there has been a slow down since `V5`.

I believe sometime since `V5` symbolic preprocessing was introduced, which can cause overhead. We can turn this off in `V10` and see a drastic speed up:

```
f[x_] := Which[-1 <= x <= 0, x, 0 <= x, x^2, True, 0]
ϕ[x_] := NIntegrate[f[t], {t, -1, x}]

Plot[ϕ[x], {x, -1.5, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
ψ[x_] := NIntegrate[f[t], {t, -1, x}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]

Plot[ψ[x], {x, -1.5, 1}] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

## Edit

I have verified that this is the reason for the slowdown. My copy of `V5` does not know about the `"SymbolicProcessing"` submethod:

[image]

Comment: +1.  I don't know when the `symbolicprocessing` option was introduced but its in v9 (same results).

Comment: +1, thanks, that is what I asked! I suspected that Math is doing something other than pure numerics.

Comment: @george2079 it looks like it was introduced in version 6. It appears in the v6 legacy documentation for `NIntegrate`: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/ref/NIntegrate.html.

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{
    {x, -1 <= x <= 0},
    {x^2, x > 0}}];

\[Phi][x_] = Assuming[Element[x, Reals],
  Integrate[f[t], {t, -1, x}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[\[Phi][x], {x, -1.5, 1}] // Timing
```

[image]